# Css-modules - change localIdentName

Tags: css, css-modules

I need to change the way css-module renames my class every time it builds.
Now is path__class-name__random-string.

```
<h1 class="header-module--Header--154UO"> I wanna die </h1>
```

I wanna change the class name from "header-module--Header--154UO" to "Header".

I'm using the v3 of Gatsby.